# Generate XML from C# Code

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have to generate specific XML data from code.
The XML needs to look like this

```
<this:declarationIdentifier xmlns:this="demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentifier"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentifier DeclarationGbIdentifier.xsd"
xmlns:nsIdentity="demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentityType">
<this:declarationIdentity>
<nsIdentity:declarationUcr>Hello World</nsIdentity:declarationUcr>
</this:declarationIdentity>
</this:declarationIdentifier>
```

I have dabbled with XmlSerializer and XDocument but cant get the output to match this exactly

Please help.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Can you share some code of your efforts and specify what exactly goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will produce your desired output.  There possibly is a simpler way this is just off the cuff to get you started.  With the prefixes that you are requiring I would look up XmlDocument and adding namespaces to it to have a better understanding of what the code below is doing.  Also what I would do is attempt to acquire the XSD schema file and use the XSD.exe to build a .cs file and then you can move forward with the XmlSerializer.  If you move forward with the code below i highly suggest moving off your namespaceuri's into some soft of settings file so you can easily modify them in the event they change.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("this", "declarationIdentifier", "demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentifier");
        root.SetAttribute("xmlns:this", "demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentifier");
        root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        //Just setting an Attribute of xsi:schemaLocation it would always drop the xsi prefix in the xml so this is different to accomodate that
        XmlAttribute schemaAtt = doc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        schemaAtt.Value = "demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentifier DeclarationGbIdentifier.xsd";
        root.Attributes.Append(schemaAtt);

        root.SetAttribute("xmlns:nsIdentity", "demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentityType");
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        XmlElement declarationIdentity = doc.CreateElement("this", "declarationIdentity", "demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentifier");

        XmlElement declarationUcr = doc.CreateElement("nsIdentity","declarationUcr","demo.org.uk/demo/DeclarationGbIdentityType");
        declarationUcr.InnerText = "Hello World";
        declarationIdentity.AppendChild(declarationUcr);

        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(declarationIdentity);
```

To output this as a string or dump it off to a file you can use the following operations, I output to a file as well as output to the console in my test app.

```
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\<Path to File>\testing.xml"))
        using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
        {
            doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
            xmlTextWriter.Flush();
            writer.Write(stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
        }
```